# How to add LostFocus Event for a TextBox in Window Apps

Tags: c#-4.0

> How to add  **LostFocus**  Event for a **TextBox**
>   I could not find it in Event Browser of Editor in VS10. i found Leave Event rather than LostFocus

Answer (score -1):

Use the Leave Event that will serve what you want

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.